# xslt - selecting element with id attribute equals to id other attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm really new to XML and XSLT. I've read some tutorials and made some simple xsl code. Now I'm struggling with this transformation and it makes me crazy, because I don't have idea how to deal with it.

I've got XML code similar to this:

```
<navigation >
  <item  id="1" >
    <item  id="6" />
    <item  id="7" >
      <item  id="18" />
      <item  id="19" />
    </item>
    <item  id="8" />
    <item  id="9" />
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <item  id="10" />
    <item  id="11" />
    <item  id="12" />
  </item>
  <item  id="3"  >
    <item  id="13" />
    <item  id="14" >
      <item  id="20" />
      <item  id="21" />
    </item>
    <item  id="15" />
  </item>
  <item  id="4" >
    <item  id="16" />
    <item  id="17" />
  </item>
  <item  id="5" />
  <current id="7" />
</navigation>
```

I need to select "item" which currently has the same "id" like "current" id element, and then check it has children - another item elements. If it has, I would like to display children "id" attribute as a nested list, and selected item and its siblings "id" attribute as a first level list.
If it has not, I would like to display selected item  and its siblings "id" as a nested list, and selected item's parent and parent's siblings as a first level list.

For example, if current id = "7" output will be like this:

```
- 6
- 7
  - 18
  - 19
- 8
- 9
```

and for example, if current id = "1" output will be like this:

```
-1
  -6
  -7
  -8
  -9
-2
-3
-4
-5
```

Comment: But the `item` with `id=7` only has the ones with ids 6, 8, 9 as siblings, the other ones you have shown are not siblings, they are at the same nesting level, but with a different parent.

Comment: right, I made a mistake. I've already edited

Comment: As for the second example with `current` being `1`, if you want to " display children "id" attribute as a nested list", shouldn't  8 and 9 not be included in the output?

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. I also made a mistake here :( Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

To find an item element by its id it makes sense to set up a key

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>
```

than way we can then use `key('id', current/@id)` to select the item referenced by the `current` element.

As for your conditions, it appears that they basically describe the same mapping, only for leaf elements you want to apply the mapping to the parent of that leaf element.

Trying to implement that with XSLT 3 I came up with

```
  <xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="navigation">
      <ul>
          <xsl:variable name="current-selection" select="key('id', current/@id)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="current-id" select="if ($current-selection[item]) then $current-selection/@id else $current-selection/../@id"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="if ($current-selection[item]) then $current-selection/../item else $current-selection/../../item">
              <xsl:with-param name="current-id" select="$current-id" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:param name="current-id"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@id = $current-id">
              <li>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                  <ul>
                      <xsl:apply-templates/>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <li>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </li>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

full example with the various inputs at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BK/3, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BK/2, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BK/1

Comment: Thanks for your help! your solution seems to be great, unfortunately I'm limited in my work to xslt 1.0. after many hours of attempts I managed to find a solution, less sophisticated than yours, but it works :) https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvL